# Android BLE: server side changes for onCharacteristicChanged callback?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an ios app in which I am doing BLE communication with a medical device. I am creating android version of same app.

In my android application for implementing BLE communication with that medical device I have written following gatt callback:

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
                gatt.discoverServices();
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "State Other");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        Log.d(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered");
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCharacteristic = gatt.getService(SNORECOACH_SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(BODY_MOVEMENT_UUID);
        if ( mCharacteristic.getUuid().equals(BODY_MOVEMENT_UUID)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic Found");
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(mCharacteristic, true);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = mCharacteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID);
        if (descriptor.getUuid().equals(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor Found");
        }
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorRead(gatt, descriptor, status);
        Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorRead");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
        Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite");
    }
};
```

All the operations like pairing, unpairing, read-write characteristics are working fine except onCharacteristicChange callback.

I have tried all the possible options at following links

1) https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

2) http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-example/

3) http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/22/android-bluetooth-low-energy-tutorial/

and many more other links.

But onCharacteristicChanged is not getting called. I have been trying for this more than 5 days but no luck.

**But in ios app callback equivalent to onCharacteristicChanged is getting called properly.**

What I would like to know is - any coding/implementation(i.e. any server side implementation) specific to Android I have to do in that device so that it can send characteristic change notification, which I can receive at onCharacteristicChanged callback.

Comment: That should work. What is printed in your log?

Comment: In log I am getting all the messages till "onDescriptorWrite" with no issue, but that onCharacteristicChanged callback is not getting triggered.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the Bluetooth HCI snoop log in Wireshark.

Comment: Maybe also have a look at the open source projects on github [here](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor))

Comment: The nRF toolbox may be the one you want. See if that works with your device then work backwards

Comment: Sorry missed to update, the issue was with server side I mean one of the characteristic was needed to set to 1, and then device started sending notifications. So the code snippet above is working perfectly. Thanks All